# presenting string and date data types in a jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a jtable with columns for both string and date data types.
 but for now every information is presented as a string data 
 I will like to present date data types in the jtable's 
 date columns.

I also present below codes for the data model

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<List<Object>> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
     private String[] header = { "ID","SUBJECT","LETTTER FROM","LETTER DATE","DATE RECEIED",
                                  "REMARKS","DATE DISPATCHED","DESTINATION OFFICE"};



    public List<List<Object>> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(List<List<Object>> dataList) {       
        this.dataList = dataList;
        fireTableDataChanged();       
        fireTableStructureChanged();        
    }

    public void setHeader(String[] header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String[] getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return header.length;
    }

    @Override
   public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return header[col];
   }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
    return dataList.get(row).get(col);
    }

}
```

any suggestion cos am new to jtable

Comment: You can try using `JCalendar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `getColumnClass` method:

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    if (isDate(columnIndex)) {
        return Date.class;
    }
    else {
        return String.class;
    }
}
```